# Distance between two x values of a parabola?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, quadratics

Given the vertex **T(0,1)** which closes the x-axes (apsis) with a surface of **5**, find distance between x-values on the x-axis?

What I've done:
from the formula of the vertex, for x-coordinate;
$$\frac{-b^2}{2a}=0 \Rightarrow b=0$$ 
from the formula of the vertex, for x-coordinate:
$$\frac{-b^2-4ac}{4a}=0 \Rightarrow c=-1$$

Now, I have a problem, when I put **x=0**, for the general equation, The **y** coordinate does not match the result? $$f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C \Rightarrow f(0)=A0+0*0-1 \Rightarrow 1 \neq-1$$
I 'm really confused with this, It seems that I've miscalculated **c**, but how? I Can't figure that out I should be getting **1=1**.Why am I not getting it?

Otherwise, I know hot to solve the problems (using Viete formulas) and then plugging x values given by the Viete formulas into my definite Integral with a Surface of 5. I solve for **A** and get x1 and x2. I hope this is correct?

Comment: What  do you mean with "a surface of 5"? What "definite Integral" are you talking about?

Comment: I have to use the definite integral to calculate my x values , I have the surface of 5, knowing that I easily get my x1 and x2 values.

Comment: I am sorry but I really do not understand. Could you take a photo of the statement of the problem on your textbook?

Comment: I have to translate it, I'll do it in a couple of hours, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: May I ask you which language are you translating from?

Comment: I doubt that you know croatian xd

Comment: Croatian? I have been learning for about a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting a comprehensible translation, I would like to point out that the vertex of the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is at the point
$$\left(-\frac{b}{2a},-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}\right).$$
Hence if the vertex is $(0,1)$ then $b=0$ and $c=1$.

I wonder if the 5 means the difference between the $y$-coordinates of the focus and the vertex which is $\frac{1}{4a}$, then we should have  $a=1/20$.

Comment: I 've now realised that I did a huge mistake because I forgot the - sign which changes the to (-bsquared+4ac). I now got my result which is 15/2 the distance betwen x1 and x2 on the x-axis...